# Get the image from DB and Path

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have successfully uploaded many images into Db and its path. The directory for is at `images/`. I have tried to get the image using `SELECT` but it's not working.

PHP

```
include ("dbConnect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM imageTable";
$path = "images/";

while($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo " <img src="$path/$image['imageName']" alt="['imagename']" /> <br /> ";
} 

$mysqli->close();
```

I have tried to retrieved the image from DB and its path but it's not working. I am wondering what I am missing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: turn on your error reporting, most likely its because of this simple contenation issue `echo " <img src="$path/$image['imageName']" alt="['imagename']" /> <br /> ";` (mind the missing dots `.` concatenation)

Comment: I have turn on the error reporting and it didn't show any @Ghost

Comment: As @Ghost mentioned `src="$path/$image['imageName']" alt="['imagename']"` should be like `src=" . $path/$image['imageName'] . " alt=" . ['imagename'] . "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo error. Here you did nor execute the query. You should execute query.

```
include ("dbConnect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM imageTable";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//Here $con is database connection link

$path = "images/";
while($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<img src="'.$path . $image['imageName'] .'" alt="'.$image['imagename'].'"> <br />';
}
```

[**MySqli Connection**](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Did you execute your query?

Comment: can you explain where `$result` comes from? It still doesn't work thou. I just executed my query using your edited answer.

Comment: FYI, I have changed $con into $mysqli which is database connection link.

Comment: $result should use for `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.